# localhost facebook app development, jquery not working

Tags: jquery, facebook, localhost

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('testing');
});
```

Error Description ;

-- Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

-- Blocked a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.facebook.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

jQuery not worked.. What is the problem ?

Comment: did u include jquery file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you linked to jquery.js file first. If it still doesnt work try to use 'jQuery' keyword instead of $ 
Like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert('testing');
});
```

Comment: I tried. still did not work :S 

my english very bad :) I'm sorry for that.

As for me.. Problem protocol related (http / https). But I don't know the solution